# DRF serializer for ContentType object return null

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I try to work with ContentTypes Framework and DRF. I have followed documentation, [generic relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships)

I have formed  `BlogPost` Model:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
```

and  `Comment` Model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I have formed `serializers`:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = "__all__"

​
class CommentedObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
​
    def to_representation(self, value):
        """
        Serialize tagged objects to a simple textual representation.
        """
        if isinstance(value, Comment):
            serializer = CommentSerializer(value)
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected type of commented object')
        return serializer.data

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentedObjectRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    time_since_publication = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
​
​
    def get_time_since_publication(self, object):
        publication_date = object.published_at
        now = datetime.now()
        time_delta = timesince(publication_date, now)
        return time_delta
​
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['id', 'pk', 'title', 'slug', 'content','comments', 'published_at', 'timestamp', 'updated',  'time_since_publication']
        read_only_fields = ('pk',)
        lookup_field = ('pk',)
​    ​
```

When I check the `api` in the browser I get `json` answer

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "pk": 1,
        "title": "this is title",
        "slug": "this-is-title",
        "content": "This is content",
        "comments": null,
        "published_at": "2019-11-15",
        "timestamp": "2019-11-15T12:14:37.336170Z",
        "updated": "2019-11-15T12:14:37.336208Z",
        "time_since_publication": "16 hours, 5 minutes"
    }
]
```

How can I get the related comments. 
Thanks

ps: here is my view function

```
class BlogPostListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        title = request.data['title']
        self.slug = slugify(title)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

class CommentListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        blogpost_pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        blogpost = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, pk=pk)
        serializer.save()

class CommentDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
```

Comment: Can you show the view function?

Comment: @funnydman I have added my view

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have switched the generic relation and reverse generic relation.  In the example you cited, the object being serialized is the `TaggedItem`, which is the model that has the generic foreign key.  But in your code you are trying to serialize a `BlogPost` object, which has the `GenericRelation` (i.e., the other side of the relationship).  From the documentation:

> Note that reverse generic keys, expressed using the GenericRelation
>   field, can be serialized using the regular relational field types,
>   since the type of the target in the relationship is always known.

Try simply removing the `CommentedObjectRelatedField` line from your serializer.  Let the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` handle the relationship.

### Update

In a cursory local attempt, it did not work to leave the field out (in this case, I get an exception stating that "Object of type GenericRelatedObjectManager is not JSON serializable").  I had to explicitly add a `HyperlinkedRelatedField` in the serializer.

Comment: hmm.  just to double check: the `BlogPost` object with `pk` 1 _does_ have some related comments, right?

Comment: I tried to check I can see them on admin panel, but I cant reach them from shell, I need some adjustments. my comment model has content_type and object_id. I have to pass those values when I  perform create.